# FontAwesome icons not showing, why?

Tags: installation, font-awesome

No matter what I try, every single time I want to install FontAwesome into any project, it does not work and I have to try and figure out for many hours why not. What is going wrong here? I've put both the `css` and `webfonts` directory into the same directory called `fontawesome`. I've linked to those files and I literally tried everything I could think of:

- URL with dots,
- URL without dots,
- no first slash,
- with first slash,
- HTML file,
- PHP file,
- Changing URLS in all.css (same as above) to point to the right path...

There is no icon showing, not even a 'missing icon' square. The file opened here is `index.php` and is located directly inside the `admin` directory (not in a subdirectory).

What am I missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this cdn link and remove all other fontawasome cdn links

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

For Example :

```html
    <html>
    
    <head>
      <title>Demo</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
      <i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! What's the difference?

Comment: Actually the cdn code you have downloaded was not correct. If this clears your doubt then please upcast this so this can be useful to others also